# What is the difference between SaveOrUpdateCopy and SaveOrUpdate in Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

What is the difference between `SaveOrUpdateCopy` and `SaveOrUpdate` method in NHibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **nHibernate** doc:

> Copy the state of the given object
>   onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no
>   persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will
>   be loaded. Return the persistent
>   instance. If the given instance is
>   unsaved or does not exist in the
>   database, save it and return it as a
>   newly persistent instance. Otherwise,
>   the given instance does not become
>   associated with the session.

There is [one nice blog post](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2009/11/nhibernate-feature-saveorupdatecopy.html) on the subject.